# Description list items: selective misbehaviour with Ligatures=TeX, fonts, xeLaTeX, and luaLaTeX

Tags: xetex, luatex, description, ligatures

I've just come across this curiosity. Can anyone tell me what's going on? Here's the mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\begin{document}
\texttt{
\begin{description}
\item[--help] Help
\item[-{}-help] Help
\end{description}}
\end{document}
```

And here are the results:

LuaLaTeX:

[image]

XeLaTeX:

[image]

I get similar results with Source Code Pro in place of Consolas.

Now, I have two issues with this:

1. `-()-` is, I believe, the canonical way to 'break' an automatic ligature. Why is LuaLaTeX producing incorrect output?
2. In defiance of `\texttt{}`, the description list [item]s are being set in Latin Modern Roman, rather than Consolas. Why?

(BTW, I appreciate I may be able to fix #2 with the `enumitem` package, but I shouldn't have to, IMO.)

Comment: `-{}-` does not work reliably, not even in Knuth TeX.  The correct way to break a ligature is and has always been `-\kern0pt-`.  LuaTeX's output is not incorrect, it's just different because they made different design decisions.

Comment: No -{}- is not the canonical way to break a ligature. It works in pdflatex sometimes (but not if pdflatex tries to find a hyphenation point there). With lualatex it never works.

Comment: Using \texttt around a whole description is rather odd, and it will not affect parts like the item description which contain a font command internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to break the ligatures if you set the mono font for the labels, because the monospaced font is loaded without the `Ligatures=TeX` option.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setmonofont{Consolas}

\newlist{ttdescriptioninner}{description}{1}
\setlist[ttdescriptioninner]{font=\ttfamily}
\newenvironment{ttdescription}
 {\ttfamily\ttdescriptioninner}
 {\endttdescriptioninner}

\begin{document}

\begin{ttdescription}
\item[--help] Help
\item[--help] Help
\end{ttdescription}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Grazie, @egreg. As I was already using `enumitem` for the real task, I fixed it there, with `format=\ttfamilt`

Answer (score 1):

My thanks to Henri Menke and Ulrike Fischer for their observations.

1. I am mistaken. `-{}-` is *not* the canonical way to break a ligature; rather, the correct way is `-\kern0pt-`.
2. This does not indicate an error in LuaLaTeX, but, rather, a design decision on the treatment of `-{}-`
3. The `enumitem` package provides features to adjust the typesetting of the item label.

Comment: note the luatex difference is not specifically about `{}` but more generally (to cope with fancier font shaping) it happens later in the process on a list of _nodes_ so constructs that do not make a node like `{}` have no effect (this is also why it sometimes fails in pdflatex if the ligatures are "reconsidered" after a hyphenation trial then only node information is available not the original markup, and the `{}` won't be seen.